# Adding horizontal overflow:auto to all images which are wider than 500px

Tags: jquery

using jquery i am trying to add css overflow:auto to all images which are wider than 500px but the code is not working, anyone know where is the problem? am i doing something wrong?

```
    .bigimg{ overflow:auto; }

<img src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/frontier_macsj0717.jpg?itok=V4q9UgHD">
<img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-85/data1/images/southtyrol350698.jpg">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('img').each(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    if (width > 400) {
      $(this).wrap("<div class='bigimg'></div>");
    }
  })

});
```

***EDIT:***

I SOLVED IT ON MY OWN:
FIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/xtudgz4c/1/

SCRIPT FOR WEBSITE:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  $("img").each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 500) {
      $(this).wrap("<div class='bigimg'></div>");
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any jquery selector which automatically selects greater than *px images?

Comment: Any room for improvement?

Comment: 'Is there any jquery selector which automatically selects greater than *px images?' No, as far as i know... So, this should be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check below updated codeon [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96jeanex/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).width() > 500){
        $(this ).wrap( "<div class='bigimg'></div>" );
    }
    });
});
```